# Django interpreter a Javascript loop as a tag / variable

Tags: javascript, django, templates, tags

I try to insert a javascript loop into a Django template in order to inject it within a block from another template.

I don't know if it's possible :

```
{% extends 'upload_form.html' %}

    #template.html
    {% block FILE_INPUT %}

    {{ block.super|safe }} <script type="text/javascript">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-upload fade">
            <!-- ... -->
            <td class="title"><label>Title: <input name="title[]" required></label></td>
            <!-- ... -->
        </tr>
    {% } %}</script>

    {% endblock %}
```

It seems that django interpreter loop " JS " as a tag / variable :

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /index/

'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8002/index/
Django Version:     1.8.5
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in do_for, line 863
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:
```

Someone would have an idea so that the script is only interpreted by the browser ?

Many Thanks.

Comment: There should be a condition. `for(var i = 0; i<10; i++)` you are missing `i<10`

Comment: Well yes.. it would if you wrap your for loop in django template syntax of course its going to think you are after a django utility. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I do not try to use a Python loop, but i try to insert a javascript loop into the Django template. Topic Edited

Comment: But... why? If you want a JS loop, use a JS loop; why are you wrapping it in Django tags?

Comment: You'r right. This is stupid. I did / could not simply change the javascript file ( static file on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jfu/ etc.... ).
I thought I could change it directly from the template, but I'll find another solution . Thank you for your replies !

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct syntax for django loop in template.
It should be like this :

```
{% for item in items %}
    (what you want to display)
{% endfor %}
```

Note that the "items" is a variable you've sent from your view.

Then, try to use a correct syntax for you loop, see what it does and tell us.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I do not try to use a Python loop, but i try to insert a javascript loop into the Django template.
Topic Edited.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can't do a js loop into a django loop. This is why you are trying do into your code : "{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}". You are opening a django loop with the "{% for".

Comment: @Slaan : you have to open a javascript markup into your django html template with : <javascript></javascript>. You can't insert javascript into html as you did. You should read the js docs first.

Comment: Yes, I see.  I'll find another solution . Thank you for your replies Raphael !

Answer (score 0):

{% verbatim %}

{{ js/agular }}

{% endverbatim %}